# Making text linkable via Tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, regexp-replace

I have written this code for a tampermonkey, got TM to execute the code using mutation observers, but nothing is changing on the page.  the goal is to turn text that passes the regex into a link to a site to lookup that value.

```
async function addeelinks(jnode) {
    /* regular expression to find all ee */
    const regex = new RegExp("^S[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}_001_v$")
    /* gets an array of all html elements where ee are known to hang out*/
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    /* steps through all the items in the array looking at each one individually */
    for (var i = 1; 1 > cells.length; i++) {
        /* grabs the contents of the td */
        var cellvalue = cells[i].firstChild.data;
        /* if the contents look like a ee then... */
        if (regex.test(cellvalue)){
            /* wrap the ee in a link to site for the ee */
            cells[i].firstChild.data = "'<a href='https://example.com/search?value='" + cellvalue + "' target='example' >'" + cellvalue + "'</a>'";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried validating my regex with example data, and its solid.  I tried swapping firstChild.data with .innerHTML based on some other question/answers I found on stack exchange, and even found suggestions to use .replace, but hitting a brick wall here.  I'm not very familiar with javascript so I assume I'm making a very basic error.

Comment: And if this is not the best way to do this extremely simple task feel free to shout out an alternative.  Thanks!

Comment: `cellvalue` is an object, therefore it will never match the regex. Could you post example HTML markup of a `td element`?

Comment: '<td>SGvMNvypD4_001_v</td>' and thanks for the pointer, lemme see what I can do to make that a string